# Browserstack marks test as pass even when they are failed

Tags: protractor

I am new to Browserstack and facing issue with updating test status. While running the automated tests, the tests are not marked as failed.

I have tried adding the below code in my protractor config file. However, it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing here?

```
 onComplete: async function(failures) {
       if (failures) {
        request({
              uri: `https://${browserstack.user}:${browserstack.key}@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/${
          browser.sessionId
        }.json`,
    method: 'PUT',
    form: {
      status: 'error'
    },
  });
}
```

},

Can anyone suggest what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

The onComplete function is expecting `(passed)` as the parameter instead of `(failuers)`.
[Here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/ed955e56a839d7f69da43acb6755763220d3681d/lib/frameworks/jasmine.js#L111) is the relevant piece of Jasmine code

You should be able to solve this by changing to

```
 onComplete: async function(passed) {
       if (!passed) {
        request({
              uri: `https://${browserstack.user}:${browserstack.key}@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/${
          browser.sessionId
        }.json`,
    method: 'PUT',
    form: {
      status: 'error'
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: The updated api url should be: " https://userName:key@api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/sessions/yourSessionID.json"